# decoding a select from sqlite table

Tags: sqlite, select, core-data

I have an sqlite database called `TaskManager.sqlite`

I populate it by using Swift Core Data.

This is what I get when I perform a `select * from "my_table"`:

```
sqlite> select * from ZTASK;
46|1|2|HOME|2015-06-19 22:00:00|<p>Ceci sont des donn&eacute;es compl&egrave;tes d'une t&acirc;che InBox</p>|58ce43a70649af0392298c87b0527d4218f95694|76bbfe695318d471a541bc3333e58eea28acae54|LATE|test complet de données simples

sqlite> select * from ZTASK;
46|1|1|MEETING|2015-10-14 22:00:00|<p>seule la derniere tache est affichee dans le TableView, pourquoi??</p>|41d0f0ddab701729ed94101d8add8a727873d761|76bbfe695318d471a541bc3333e58eea28acae54|LATE|Tache qui fait disparaitre les precedentes...
```

On my CoreData, I have my entity Task that contain 7 attributes, not 10 like the select says.

The first value I insert on base is the "MEETING,HOME", the fourth one. My question is, what are the 3 first values, what do they mean, why are they here?

I feel the "46" is a kind of id, maybe the 46th insert I do on this base?
the first "1" I have no idea...
the second "1" or "2" is, in my opinion, to say it's the first insert or the second insert of the 46th "global" insert? This is only feeling and suppositions, I have no real idea about what that mean.

If anyone knows what it really means

Answer (score 0):

Ok, This is what are the 3 values:

`Z_PK INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`that is the primary key, `Z_ENT INTEGER`is the entity id, used for tracking the primary key of the object in the Z_PK table and deals with inheritance, `Z_OPT INTEGER` counts the number of time a row has been written/rewritten so starts at 1..